# meaning of "tending to" in "life constantly needs tending to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "tending to" in this context:

> Life is not like getting your driver’s license. It’s not a clear path with all the milestones from now to success perfectly staked out. Life is like being married to yourself. It constantly needs **tending to**, or else you’ll wake up one day and wonder what you have become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Tend to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tend-to-sb-sth)* is a phrasal verb that means dealing with the problems of something. Here, the sentence is saying that you constantly need to deal with the problems of life.